# Assign an optional value to a UItextfield / UIlabel which aren't a string

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

I have an app with club -> members -> transactions, which are hierarchical.
Now I want to implement the function, to edit e.g. the amount of a transaction. The reason of a transaction isn't difficult, but I cannot assign a optional type of a `Double?` to a `textfield` or `label`.

So my question is: How can I assign this to it?/ How can I convert it to a string?

This error is shown to me : `Cannot invoke initializer for type 'String' with an argument list of type '(Double?)/(Date?)'`

This is my code:

```swift
reasonlbl.text = transaction?.reason
dateLbl.text = String(transaction?.date)
amountLbl.text = String(transaction?.money)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
if let money = transaction?.money {
    amountLbl.text = "\(money)"
}
```

//

```
if let date  = transaction?.date {
  let formatter = DateFormatter()
  formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" // set it as your format
  dateLbl.text = formatter.string(from:date)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally, you would want to do safety checks before doing that, like this:

```
guard transaction = transaction else {
  return
}
```

or

```
if let date = transaction.date {
...your code
}
```

also if you want, you can assign default values if transactoin object is null

```
let date = transaction?.date ?? Date()

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd 'at' HH:mm"

let dateString = formatter.string(from: date)
```

---

Another approach is following:

```
amountLbl.text = "\(transaction?.money ?? 0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
amountLbl.text = String(format: "%f", transaction?.money)
```

A similar conversion would happen for date.

Comment: This won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a number into a string you can use a `NumberFormatter` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)) they are an amazing object, because they not only convert a number to a text or viceversa but they also take into account the current locale on user device, for instance they modify the decimal seprator.
For the date is the same you should use a `DateFormatter`([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter)).

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .currency
amountLbl.text = formatter.string(from: transaction!.money) 

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
 dateLbl.text = dateFormatter.string(from: transaction!.date)
```

Pay attention that used force unwrap for your `transaction` object, but you MUST handle the correct unwrapping or it will crash.